# How do I get a remote user's IP address on Node.JS when proxied through Apache ProxyPass?

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy

We have an apache web server, which has a proxypass on /iptozip (this is proxied to localhost:1337, where our Node.JS server is listening)

However, when the Node.JS server receives the request, it gets the IP address of the Apache web server, and not the remote user. How do I get the remote users IP address?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app **lives behind a proxy** server , you need to **look at** the `X-Forwarded-For` header instead of the `remote ip address` (source IP).

Comment: The X-forwarded-for header that comes over is the IP of the apache server. How do I get it to pass the correct IP?

Comment: I cant answer these, the X-Forwarded-For environment variable should also be set by default.(with apache mod_proxy).

Comment: I figured it out - I was in Incognito mode in Chrome, and it screwed with the cookies

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented [forwarded-for](https://github.com/primus/forwarded-for) on my node.js web server behind Apache proxy - works like a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: wow, 7+ years later. And still good advice! Thanks!